# why i cant change elements of 3d array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

weights = np.random.standard_normal((2,2,3))
b = weights
c = weights
c[0,1,:] = c[0,1,:] + [1,1,1]

print b[0,1]
print ('##################')
print c[0,1]
print ('##################')
print (np.sum(b-c))
```

the result is

```
[ 1.76759245  0.87506255  2.83713469]
##################
[ 1.76759245  0.87506255  2.83713469]
##################
0.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

as you can see, elements have not been changed.
why?

thanks in advance

Comment: Because both `b` and `c` are views to the same locations in the array `weights`.

Comment: The elements have been changed. `b` and `c` are the same array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, they did change. The problem is that you're referencing the same object, and only viewing it after the change. If you instead use `copy()` on `b`, you will see the values prior to the change. `b` and `c` are the same object in your current code; [Is Python call-by-value or call-by-reference? Neither.](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) is a decent read for this in a broader sense.

```
import numpy as np

weights = np.random.standard_normal((2,2,3))
b = weights.copy() # Create a new object
c = weights
c[0,1,:] = c[0,1,:] + [1,1,1]

print b[0,1]
print ('##################')
print c[0,1]
print ('##################')
print (np.sum(b-c))
```